# can't access php with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I've got the Problem that I can't reach my php file with my $.ajax() call. I always get
a jqXHR.status of 0. This is my code:

***function with $.ajax() call:***

```
function updateClubInfo(text) {
    var data = text;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '../php/updateInfo.php',
        data: {
            infoText: data,
            action: "update"
        },
        success: function() {
            // do nothing
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've build this request similar to others in my project, but this one is the only one
that doesn't work. Here the PHP file I want to reach:

***php code snippet (updateInfo.php):***

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $text = $_POST['data'];

    myLog($action);
    myLog($text);

    echo "hello";


    /*
     * Writes entry in Logfile
     */
    function myLog($data) {
        $text = @file_get_contents('log.txt');
        $text = $text . "\n" . $data;
        @file_put_contents('log.txt', $text);
    }   
?>
```

When I try to reach this PHP file in the URI the echo is outputted. So I think the
Problem should be in the ajax call.

Does someone has an Idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm grateful for any help.

Thx alot for your help
Cris

Comment: What response do you get using the Firefox or Chrome debugging tools? Do you get any error messages in the response? What http status code?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can access your script with "../" - never used it myself. Try instead using a path like "/path/to/php/updateInfo.php"

Comment: In Chrome, you can use the Network tab in the dev tools. Try to run your form and look for your ajax call and check the results.

Comment: In the Network tab in the dev tools my ajax call gets canceled, no http status code.

Comment: Try using the full url. So use something like: `http://your-website/php/updateInfo.php`

Comment: Because your AJAX request asks for JSON data, but you are writing only text in your PHP file. Therefore, the AJAX request interprets the answer as void, then HTTP status = 0

Comment: I've observed something strange with chrome dev tools. When I put a Breakpoint at the closing bracket of my updateClubInfo() function, the  ajax call works and the success alert gets outputted.

Answer (score 2):

You have a copy/paste error in your PHP file. It should be :

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
$text = $_POST['infoText'];//instead of $_POST['data']
```

**UPDATE**

Because your AJAX request asks for JSON data, but you are writing only text in your PHP file. Therefore, the AJAX request interprets the answer as void, then HTTP status = 0

**Solution**

`dataType` option is not about the type of data you are sending to the server, but the type or data you are expecting back from the server. Change `dataType: 'json',` to `dataType: 'html',` or symply remove it to let JQuery chose the appropriate mode.

Comment: +1, although it is an error, I wouldn't call it a syntax error.

Comment: thx... that was a copy paste error.
But I still get the status 0

Comment: I've removed the dataType option, also tried with dataType : 'html'. The Problem still consists

Comment: Too bad. Let the dataType removed, it really was one of the problems.

Comment: Yep was a good idea... i'm trying to understand why does the ajax call works when I set a Breakpoint, but I don't get it...

_I've observed something strange with chrome dev tools. When I put a Breakpoint at the closing bracket of my updateClubInfo() function, the ajax call works and the success alert gets outputted_

Answer (score 0):

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
$text = $_POST['data'];

myLog($action);
myLog($text);
$arr[] ='hello';

echo json_encode($arr);


/*
 * Writes entry in Logfile
 */
function myLog($data) {
    $text = @file_get_contents('log.txt');
    $text = $text . "\n" . $data;
    @file_put_contents('log.txt', $text);
}   


json data fetch only in array
```